# Why sometimes I can set framerate sometimes I can't?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

Why I get the following when I try to get camera feed from Logitech webcam?

```
The driver changed the time per frame from X to Y
```

Sometimes it happens sometimes it doesn't.

How should I resolve this problem?

Comment: Share full command and console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that camera has many different pixel_formats supported and they have different framerates specification. Check the pixel_format you used, it is likely that the default pixel_format does not support the framerate you want.